# Group items in array every 5 items and add a dash in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, grouping

I'm building a loop that in my mind will output an array of items divided by a range of 5 numbers. I tried a few function like range, sort, implode, but I haven't found the right solution yet.

So far my code is the following:

```
foreach (range(0, 100, 5) as $number) {
  echo $number;
  print implode("-", str_split($number));
}
```

My goal is to output something like:

```
1-5
5-10
10-15
```

and so on that I can associate to anything, so essentially a range of numbers every a certain amount of numbers.

Plus I'm not sure if it's the right loop.

I guess I can obtain pretty much the same result with a for loop like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i+=5)
{
     implode("-", str_split($i));
}
```

Where's my mistake?

UPDATE
I probably forget to mention that everything is in a select item:

```
<select class="drops" name="largesan">
    <option selected value> -- How Many Sandwiches? -- </option><?php
    foreach (range(0, 100, 5) as $numbers)
    {
        $mynumber = $numbers . '-' . $numbers + 5;
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $numbers;?>"><?php echo $mynumber;?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a foreach of this type

```
  foreach (range(0, 90, 5) as $number) {
    $myStr = $number . '-'. $number + 5 ;
    echo '<option value="'. $myStr .'">'. $myStr.'</option>' ;

  }
```

This is the code you should use  ..

```
select class="drops" name="largesan"> 
  <option selected value> -- How Many Sandwiches? -- </option>
    <?php 
        foreach (range(0, 90, 5) as $number) { 

              $myStr = $number . '-'. $number + 5 ; 
              echo '<option value="'.  $myStr. '">'. $myStr .'</option>' ;
        }

     ?> 
 </select>
```

Comment: what's mean "not working" ... you have error ?  ... wrong result ?  ... no result ?  ... don't work in coding is not a valid info  ..

Comment: Sure, sorry: the output is:

0 5 10 15 and it continues until it reach 105

Comment: and the problem is 105 ?

Comment: no I need to output this: a group of two items of the array like 1-5, 5-10, 10-15 until 100

Comment: this  ... what ?

Comment: to insert in a dynamic select item and generate something like that:
<select class="drops" name="largesan">
                    <option selected value> -- How Many Sandwiches? -- </option><?php
                    foreach (range(0, 100, 5) as $numbers)
                    {
                        $mynumber = $numbers . '-' . $numbers + 5;
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $numbers;?>"><?php echo $mynumber;?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>

Comment: my is a suggestion for build the numeric info .. i have update the answer  .. you can easly add the info  for you html tag ..

Comment: Thi is exactly what I did (I updated my answer too) and it didn't work because the output is the following:
HOW MANY SANDWICHES: 5 10 15 20 and so on for some reason the dash and the other part of the code doesn't work

Comment: looking to the code  .. i provided .. seems strange that don't show all the option from 0-5    to 95-100

Comment: This is literally my code:

<select class="drops" name="largesan">
                    <option selected value> -- How Many Sandwiches? -- </option><?php
                    foreach (range(0, 90, 5) as $number) {
                        $myStr = $number . '-'. $number + 5 ;
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $myStr;?>"><?php echo $myStr;?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>

Comment: Except this part, I echo the value inside the html, but it won't change the result

Comment: I don't see any " -- How Many Sandwiches? -- "  in your link  .. are you sure for the link  ???'

Comment: it's in => Your Order => Sandwich Trays => Large Sandwiches ($4.05 per sandwich)

Comment: I found the bug, I'm gonna post the solution in a minute

Comment: The problem is that it wasn't quite right. See my code above

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the select item is:

```
<select class="drops" name="largesan">
    <option selected value> -- How Many Sandwiches? -- </option><?php
    foreach (range(0, 95, 5) as $numbers)
    {
        $mynumber = $numbers . '-' . $numbers + 5;
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $mynumber;?>"><?php echo $numbers .'-'. $mynumber;?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Which means that a loop that prints a certain range of numbers, for example from 0 to 100 each, for another example, 5 numbers is the following:

```
foreach (range(0, 95, 5) as $numbers) {
$mynumber = $numbers . '-' . $numbers +5;
echo $numbers . '-' .mynumber;
}
```